# Android studio - Broadcast receiver... how to dump the input?

Tags: android, broadcast, receiver

I have an android studio app on a zebra device with inbuilt barcode scanner.
Using broadcast receiver, I am successfully intercepting and using the scanned input.

However - I cant find a way of 'dumping' the input after interception... it just seems to have to go somewhere, either into any text field it can find which might have focus, or if a button, for example , has focus, it flickers each time a character is received.

I suspect there is a way of erasing the input after interception, but I cant find it.

Has anyone had the same issue?

The code I am using is very simple but seems to work:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
     @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String code = intent.getStringExtra(DATA);
         if (scantype.contains("LASER")) {
            try {
                process_code(code);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: You need to explain what you're trying to do more clearly.  All we see here is a very generic function named process being called, we have no idea what you want to do with it/are trying to do with it

Comment: Thank Gabe.   Android device has a barcode scanner which, if the focus is on a text field, populates the text field with its output.  Broadcast receiver intercepts the process, so I can programmatically capture the output and process it before it reaches the text field.  I need to be able to , after capturing the output, stop it from  going on to the text field. if current focus is, say a control, the output still attempts to go there causing it to flicker. For the barcode scanner to work, it has to have focus on a visible component. So I need a function like  Afterreceive.eraseinput but what?